# Gunicorn + pyramid 'OPTIONS' method has stopped working

Tags: pyramid, gunicorn

I have an app server and api server running with gunicorn. Both servers are pyramid apps.

Browser loads html and static files from app server and then talks to api server directly.

Browser needs to do a file upload operation. This has always worked. I have done the following for the OPTION method that does file upload because it is a cross domain post

```
response.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = origin
```

The issue is that the local machine has started timing out the OPTION call to the api server. The first time this error shows up

```
File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 87, in handle
    req = six.next(parser)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/parser.py", line 39, in __next__
    self.mesg = self.mesg_class(self.cfg, self.unreader, self.req_count)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 152, in __init__
    super(Request, self).__init__(cfg, unreader)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 49, in __init__
    unused = self.parse(self.unreader)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 167, in parse
    line, rbuf = self.read_line(unreader, buf, self.limit_request_line)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 217, in read_line
    self.get_data(unreader, buf)
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/message.py", line 155, in get_data
    data = unreader.read()
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 38, in read
    d = self.chunk()
  File "/home/ranjith/workspace/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn-0.17.4-py2.7.egg/gunicorn/http/unreader.py", line 65, in chunk
    return self.sock.recv(self.mxchunk)

error: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
2013-05-27 11:37:17 [19097] [INFO] Handling signal: winch
2013-05-27 11:37:17,533 ERROR [gunicorn.error][MainThread] Error processing request.
```

And after that it stops working altogether. All other calls work. The OPTIONS call used to work. I am not sure why this is not working and it has left me frustrated. The same works on our test servers etc. I am not sure what is broken and why

Comment: I know this was a year ago, but did you ever get to the bottom of this? I am running a django app with gunicorn on heroku and I get the same error, but it only happens when requests are made from one specific computer.

Comment: SIGWINCH signifies that the window size has changed for the terminal the application is running in. This is not a Pyramid issue.